# How to view data in table per pagination with searching,sorting and pagination

Tags: angular6, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to display data in a table view(`ag-grid-angular`) with searching, sorting, and pagination in my angular 6 projects.

My data is coming from the spring boot API.

I am having thousands of records from this API coming, I want to break this fetching in set of 20 records as per pagination from angular end, so that my API at a time fetch only 20 records.

I am not able to find any help online regarding this data table pagination stuff on angular end, I want to pass start and end index to boot API every time I got to the next page.

**truck-list.component.Html:**

```
 <div class="top-bar clearfix">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="cteateTruck()">Create 
   Truck</button>  
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <ag-grid-angular
 style="width: 1950px; height:900px;" 
 class="ag-theme-balham"
 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
 [enableSorting]="true"
 [enableFilter]="true"
 [animateRows]="true"
 [pagination]="true"
 (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

**truck-component.ts**

```
 constructor(private http : HttpClient, private router:Router){
  console.log("controller is call.")
  this.columnDefs = [
    {
  headerName: "Truck Number", 
  field: "conveyancenumber",
  width:380,
  sortingOrder:["asc","desc",null]
  },
  {
    headerName:"Truck Type",
    field:"conveyancetype",
    width:380,
    sortingOrder:["asc","desc",null]
   },
   {
    headerName:"Last Update",
    field:"lastupdate",
    width:387,
    sortingOrder:["asc","desc",null]
   }];
  }

 onGridReady(params){

 this.gridApi=params.Api;
 this.gridColumnApi=params.gridColumnApi;
 this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/abcd/getTrucksRecord")
 .subscribe(data => {
  params.api.setRowData(data);
 }
  );
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked [ngx-pagination](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging) ?

Comment: Not tried yet. Let me check.